# How to save tableviewcell state?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

[image]

I am successfully saving the state of tableviewcell by saving the state of cell to dictionary of [IndexPath:Bool] , everything is working fine but problem is when I check mark any cell , a cell from bottom also get strokethrough effect . Only selected cell is supposed to be check marked and strikethrough. Check the image in which bottom is not selected but getting strike through effect , How to resolve this ?

**TableViewCell code**

```
 let checkedImage = (UIImage(named: "success")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))! as UIImage

let uncheckedImage = (UIImage(named: "verified")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal))! as UIImage


var isChecked: Bool = false {
    didSet{
        if isChecked {
            tableRadioButton.setImage(checkedImage, for: .normal)
            lblItemName.strikeThrough(true)
            lblItemQty.strikeThrough(true)
        } else {
            tableRadioButton.setImage(uncheckedImage, for: .normal)
            lblItemName.strikeThrough(false)
            lblItemQty.strikeThrough(false)

        }

    }
}

@IBAction func RadioButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    isChecked = !isChecked
    radioButtonTapAction?(isChecked)

}
```

**Code of cell for row**

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomOrderDetailCell
    cell.setCellData(itemDetail: arrForProducts[indexPath.section].items![indexPath.row],currency: self.currency)
    
    let selected = selectedButtonIndex[indexPath] ?? false
    cell.isChecked = selected
    
    
    cell.radioButtonTapAction = {
        (checked) in
        selectedButtonIndex[indexPath] = checked
        print(checked)
    }
```

Comment: if you change the `cell.isChecked` for false, does it help?

Comment: it doesn't helping on that particular cell which is strikethrough automatically , that strike through is always same that cell but check mark is working fine